# problem with Nestjs unit test of provider

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I'm new with testing

this is my App simplified diagram

[image]

I wanna to test `UserService` .

User Service Provider is depended on TypeOrmModule .

and this is **userService.spec.ts**

```js
describe('test UserService', () => {
    let app: INestApplication;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [UserModule],
        }).compile()

        app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
        await app.init();

    });
    afterAll(async () => {
        await app.close();
    });
});
```

But this gives me an error

**Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument DataSource at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.**

what's the **problem** and how can I **fix** that ?

Comment: have you read this: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#auto-mocking Also, read this article: [Advanced Testing Strategies with Mocks in NestJS](https://trilon.io/blog/advanced-testing-strategies-with-mocks-in-nestjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test a service in isolation only define a `TestingModule` with the essential files.

By example, let say you have a `UserService` as follow:

```js
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import type { Repository } from 'typeorm';

import { User } from './user.entity';

export class UserService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>) {}

  async getOne(id: User['id']): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { id } });

    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`User not found with id: ${id}`);
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

Then you write some unit tests to check if your code works as expected:

```js
import { NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import type { Repository } from 'typeorm';

import { User } from './user.entity';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

describe('UserService', () => {
  let service: UserService;
  let mockedRepository: jest.Mocked<Repository<User>>

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          // Register the test double (mock) of the TypeORM repository
          provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
          // Create a simple object with only the required methods
          useValue: {
            findOne: jest.fn()
          },
        },
        UserService,
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get(UserService);
    mockedRepository = module.get(getRepositoryToken(User));
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should get one user', async () => {
    // Arrange
    mockedRepository.findOne.mockResolvedValueOnce(new User());

    // Act
    const user = await service.getOne(1);

    // Assert
    expect(user).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should fail if the user not exist', async () => {
    // Arrange
    mockedRepository.findOne.mockedResolvedValueOnce(null);

    // Act and Assert
    await expect(service.getOne(0)).rejects.toThrow(NotFoundException);
  });
});
```

As you can see it's easy to test the components in isolation rather than test the module as a whole.